# How to show that every non-trivial orbit of ODE is a periodic circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am working with this system of first-order ODEs.
\begin{align}
\dot{x} & = y^2 - x^2 \ ,\\
\dot{y} & = - 2 x y\ .
\end{align}

We were told to convert the system using $z=x+iy$ where I found that $z'=-z^2$. From there we were asked to show that every other orbit is a circle. I am not sure where to begin. I also looked at the rest point which occurs at the origin and believe it to by hyperbolic.

Comment: You missed a sign, it should be $z'=-z^2$. As $z^{-1}$ is a line, by circle inversion $z$ follows a circle on the complex sphere

Comment: There are nonperiodic solutions of the form $x(t)=1/(t+c)$, $y(t)=0$ for $t\geq 0$, whose orbit is not a circle.

Comment: Also these solutions follow a circle if you close the complex plane to the Riemann sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will ask you to criticize my decision, because I just thought of it, there may be inaccuracies.

I assumed that
$$ t, x(t),y(t) \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$ z(t) = x(t) + y(t)i ,  $$
$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt}i$$
$$ -z^{2} = (y^2 - x^2) - 2x\cdot y \cdot i $$
$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = -z^2$$
$$ \frac{1}{z} = t + C$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant
$$ \frac{x-yi}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} + \left[\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\right ] i =  t + C $$
we understand that $ t + C = t + (A + Bi) \in \mathbb{C}
\Rightarrow$
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   \frac{x(t)}{x^{2}(t)+y^2(t)} = t + A, 
   \\
   \frac{-y(t)}{x^2(t)+y^2(t)} = B,
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
from the second equation we obtain the equation of a circle with a center at a point $(0 ; - \frac{1}{2B})$ and a radius $\frac{1}{2|B|}$
$$  x^2 + y^2 = \frac{-y}{B}$$
$$ x^2 + y^2 + \frac{2y}{2B} + \left(\frac{1}{2B}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2B}\right)^2 $$

$$ x^2 + \left(y + \frac{1}{2B} \right)^2 = \left(\frac{1}{2B}\right)^2 $$

If you decide to count this decision as correct, then I want to warn you that Lutz Lehmann helped me

Comment: Tell me please, would it be correct if I supplement my decision after your comments?

Comment: Yes, of course. From pure esthetics an answer should either be complete and comprehensible, or just the necessary hints to help the OP along their way. There are some contradicting concerns about too short answers and math.SE not being a home-work service, but then the aim is to be a Q&A site, so having near encyclopedic answers for the more profound questions (not meaning a thick book, but an article suitable for such a big book),...